# What is meant by namespaced content and what advantages does it have?

Tags: html, html5, namespace, xhtml

I was reading [this blog](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/jun/18/html/) by  James Bennett regarding HTML vs XHTML . He writes :

> I don’t have any need for namespaced content; I’m not displaying any
>   complex mathematical notation here and don’t plan to, and I don’t use
>   SVG for any images. So that’s one advantage of XHTML out the window. I
>   also don’t have any need for XML tools; all the processing I need to
>   do can be handled by HTML-parsing libraries like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). That’s
>   the other advantage gone.

What does he mean by `namespaced content` and what advantage does it provide us ?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XML namespaces allow including XML elements defined in a schema other than that of the main document. Specifically, the article talks about [MathML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathml) and [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svg), which are XML-based formats that can be directly embedded in an XHTML document using namespaces, looking like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  XHTML content goes here
  <m:math>
      MathML content goes here
  </m:math>
  more XHTML content
</html>
```